# BottomNavigationView covering whole activity

Tags: android, navigation, nav, bottomnavigationview

I'm struggling with a simple bottom navbar. Here is the sample code generated by Android Studio:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BottomNav">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="@color/dir_primary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The issue that I'm having is that this is creating a whole layout which is covering my main layout each time I trigger to open the bottom nav like so:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pknRhMj0psn0sAIbX7-WU1KMq-ZvpRz-

I opening the nav using an Intent of an activity called BottomNav. Each time I trigger the nav it opens that whole white space along with the bottom red nav. I just want the bottom nav to popup on top of my main layout and not cover it. However, if I remove the ConstraintLayout I remove the unwanted white space but the nav sits on top and not on the bottom. This is driving me crazy. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is this layout used ? try setting `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `ConstraintLayout` . Add code where you used this layout if problem persists.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I'm calling the activity containing the BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener from a fragment. The code is very long however. Dunno if that helps though :/